# Are there any alternatives to Flappy Bird?

Tags: android, game

Flappy bird was a side scrolling game released for iOS and Android in which you controlled a bird flying across the screen by tapping on the screen to make the bird move up the screen.

[image]

This game has since been removed from the iOS app store and from Google Play.

The specific features that I'm after are:

- For Android (I have no Apple devices)
- Automatic side scrolling
- Tap for vertical movement gameplay
- Preferably ad free but I don't mind if the game is free

Are there any alternative games that provide similar gameplay with the same mechanics?

Comment: I know a more irritating version: http://www.mrspeaker.net/dev/game/flappy/

Comment: @Ranveer: And the "irritation" is that it doesn't actually do anything?!

Comment: @w3d it does! It tests your typing accuracy

Comment: @Ranveer: Ah yes, so it does! Sorry, pressed every key and button apart from the correct ones; being dense! (Dang, that IS irritating! ;)

Comment: Yes there is this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I19S5RbtcY

Comment: nice question, Flyk! Keep it up :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic - since game requests don't match the scope of the site - see this [meta post for more details](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51/are-video-game-related-questions-on-topic/224#224)

Comment: Clumsy Bird is out, almost smiler -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seriouscorp.clumsybird

Comment: Flappy Bird is probably an (inferior) clone of an older game named SFCave.  Nowadays, you can download SFCave on either Android or IOS for free.

Answer (score 9):

[Canabalt](http://adamatomic.com/canabalt/) is terrific. No birds ... except maybe the flock of pigeons that flies away from time to time. Try it free online at link provided.

Basically, your little guy runs and runs along the tops of buildings, leaping gaps, dodging obstacles, faster ... farther ... (splat!). :) Decent music, too, although you may want to listen to your own thing.

[image: Android info screenshot]

As for OP's specific criteria:

- [image: Y] For Android (I have no Apple devices)
- [image: Y] Automatic side scrolling
- [image: Y] Tap for vertical movement gameplay
- [image: M] Preferably ad free but I don't mind if the game is free : **N.b.** is [£1.99 where I am](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fishnoodle.canabalt)

I haven't played this in Android, only on the web in a browser; it is quite addictive (sadly, or gladly depending on your point of view). It is ridiculous that such simple game play can be so satisfying; see also the [details on gameplay in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canabalt).

[image: Screenshot]

(P.s. I don't know about the "mechanics" of Flappy Bird, but Canabalt is side-scrolling, anyway...)

Comment: Did you play this? Whats your experience? Could you add a screenshot? Could you elaborate a bit more? If possible have a look at this meta: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer - hope that improved the quality. Original reply was worth a DV. :)

Comment: cannabalt's dev has a proper [flappy bird](http://adamatomic.com/flappybalt/) clone

Answer (score 6):

There a a few found on [this website](http://readwrite.com/2014/02/15/flappy-bird-alternatives#awesm=~owgFBt6xhFeJ3H)
The one that is most similar would be Flappy Doge and it looks and works almost the same except that the bird is replaced by a dog. It is on the Google Play store (a quick search will find it). I have played it and it is just as fun as the original.
There is also FlapMMO found [here](http://www.flapmmo.com) where you play with other players. It is PC/Mac only and works in your browser if you are interested.

[image]

Comment: Did you play this? Whats your experience? Could you add a screenshot? Could you elaborate a bit more? If possible have a look at this meta: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I have played it and it works fine. I will add a screenshot

Comment: Thank you. As it stands your answer is a little more than "You can find stuff like this there" and a link. If this community wants to bloom we will need better answers. Please do read the discussion in the meta link I send you above to get an idea what is necessary to make answers great.

Comment: This is actually a modified version of Flappy Bird, as opposed to something that's just similar.  You can give some kudos to the developer here... http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2641908