# an offline iOS app that keeps me busy for 20 minutes

Tags: ios, game, iphone-app

I'm going crazy during train rides every morning and evening because most apps don't work well offline. I'm not looking to interact, but mostly to "read" stuff.

Depending on my mood I like apps like these:

- Quotes from bash.org (see the french version on the appstore, DansTonChat)
- VDM/FML
- 9Gag
- Some addictive/challenging game, that could be as simple as pressing one button to achieve something stupid. Like flappy birds or the stuff that ketchapp makes. "one button apps"

Though these are only examples, I'm really lacking some apps that can keep my head distracted and light for my morning ride, and I would just love some recommendations.

Don't be afraid to give me more than 1 app, worst case scenario is that I won't like it and it'll still keep me busy for 1 trip :D

I obviously have excellent data access outside of the train so if it only needs to sync "every once in a while" it'd be a sufficient network requirement for me. 100% offline apps are obviously easier but not required.

Get your guns out guys !

Comment: Seems pretty open-ended/opinion based. You're asking for an open-ended list of things to entertain you.

Comment: But if you like to read, have you considered installing an eReader, and reading a book?

Comment: Waw. I actually havent.

Comment: I usually like reading articles and just news about science or technology, when it comes to novels I'm really a poor reader, and I feel like it's not the kind of reading that is "okay" to do 20 minutes here and there, isn't it?

Comment: Subscribe to New Scientist, etc., download before setting off then read on the train.

Comment: I reckon this question is due for closure, but you can try [Canbalt](http://adamatomic.com/canabalt/) (see [earlier Q&A](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1345/435)) and [grab it if you like it enough](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/canabalt/id333180061?mt=8).

Comment: Also consider RSS readers which can download entire articles. Those articles can be news, tech-stuff, or even comics – depending on what you prefer. And ***you*** define those contents, selecting from available sources. // But as said before: the way your question is currently phrased, it is much too broad. Consider splitting it up to multiple questions, e.g. asking 1) for an eBook reader, 2) for an RSS reader, 3) … – and don't forget to check with [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) :)

Comment: @Zil: If you enjoy it, of course it's "okay." There aren't any "Novel police" who stop you from reading. But who said you have to read novels? Read whatever you like. You can read books on science... or even articles, on an eReader.  Or even in a web browser in offline mode.

Answer (score 2):

**Recomendation 1**
I recommend you to use [Stockfish Chess](https://stockfishchess.org).

Its one of the worlds best and powerful chess engine.

**Good News:**
 1. Its Free and Open-Source
 2. It runs on multiple platforms
 3. It can be played offline

You can play it in the *tournament mode*, so both you and your iOS device get exactly 5 minutes to complete the game, and the game will end within 10 minutes. So assuming both the players use all the given time, you can play 2 games, 10 minutes for each.

Its fun and challenging.

And as this is just a *for-fun-game*, you can ask any friend of yours to accompany you, so it will be *you-and-your-friend vs Stockfish-on-apple-device*.

Comment: I'm downloading that right now, as I am sitting on the train dock

Comment: @Zil great! I hope u found it fun. Ill be suggesting more as a different answer

Comment: Thanks :) anything relaxing or not too mind-heavy is perfect

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendation 2**
*Bad Piggies*

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Piggies):

> ***Bad Piggies*** is a puzzle video game developed by Rovio Entertainment, and was its first spin-off to Angry Birds. The game launched on Android, iOS, Windows and Mac on September 27, 2012. Unlike the Angry Birds games, the player controls the pigs in building devices that travel on land and air to find pieces of a map to find and take away the Angry Birds' eggs. As of October 2012, Bad Piggies was the fastest-selling game on the Apple App Store, and the quickest one to reach the top of the list, in just three hours. It was released for BlackBerry 10 in October 2013 and for Windows Phone in April 2014.